# Azure function sometimes does not insert row into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function. It works fine except one thing: it does not always insert content into the Azure SQL server although the content is always the same. According to the logs, the function is triggered, but no rows are inserted. It seems like it occurs randomly. Here is the code:

```
public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(myIoTHubMessage);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myIoTHubMessage))
    {
        try
        {
            var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db-messaging"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                conn.Open();
                log.Info("Connection opened");
                var text = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE] VALUES ('{myIoTHubMessage}')";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                {
                    var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();                    
                }
            }
            log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"C# Event Hub trigger function exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does logs have any info

Comment: The logs say the function started and completed successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either await the ExecuteNonQueryAsync() method somewhere or not use the Async method in this case.

I think your using block ends before the method is finished.

**Extra explanation**: The using block makes sure Dispose() is called. Calling Dispose() is a good thing since you are using connections to external resources (the sql server). If you dont call Dispose the connection might remain active while your program doesnt need to reserve the connection anymore.

However, because the call to the async method was not "awaited", the program did not wait for ExecuteNonQueryAsync() to finish (because it ran in the "background") before disposing the connection.

Sometimes the ExecuteNonQueryAsync() was finished before Dispose() was called, and sometimes ExecuteNonQueryAsync() was too slow. Matter of "luck". This explains the differences in your result.

On using block: [MSDN on using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

On aysnc methods: [MSDN on Async Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wow XWIKO, you are the man! Now it works every time when the function is triggered.

Comment: Yeah, that's called a race.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code of the function:

```
public static async void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(myIoTHubMessage);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myIoTHubMessage))
    {
        try
        {
            var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db-messaging"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                conn.Open();
                log.Info("Connection opened");
                var text = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[MESSAGE] VALUES ('{myIoTHubMessage}')";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                {
                    var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();                    
                    //log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
                }
            }
            log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"C# Event Hub trigger function exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I would still recommend either using "var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();" or "var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" in the using block you previously had :).

Comment: Yup, you are right, it also works. Thank you so much! You've saved my day xD